# How to add string array to ListView uing BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I wanted to create a list view and populate it with string array so I trid it with ArrayAdapter. This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String str[]={"A","S","S","P","S","S","P","Bl","Ra","M","a","a","c","s","s","ds"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);

        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

 lv.setAdapter(ad);


    }
}
```

I was wondering that if BaseAdapter is superclass of ArrayAdapter then how to make same program with BaseAdapter?

Comment: Make custom adapter

Comment: what for if your `ArrayAdapter` works fine?

Comment: Why do you need a BaseAdapter if the code works fine?

Comment: just curious about how to do it with BaseAdapter. Can we do it with base adapter or we can only do it with ArrayAdapter only?

Comment: @Piyush How to do that can you explain a little more?

Comment: A custom class that `extends ArrayAdapter<String>` is a custom adapter, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a `BaseAdapter` like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] data;

public CustomAdapter(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) convertView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = li.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);//set layout for displaying items
    TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);//get id for Text view
    txt.setText(data[position]);
    return view;
}
}
```